# Accessing webpage hosted in Guest VM from Host machine

Tags: git, windows-7, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I've got an Ubuntu VM in VirtualBox (v4.2.0-r80737) running on my Windows 7 box that's hosting a git repo, website, and a few other dev tools. It is easily accessible from other machines, and on the host machine via proxies, but I am unable to access the site/repo directly on the host machine.

The network setup in VirtualBox for the VM is as follows:
Attached to: Bridged Adapter
Adapter Type: Intel PRO/1000MT Desktop
Promiscuous Mode: Deny
Cable Connected

My guess would be that the host is trying to connect to the webpage via the LAN, rather than the wider Internet, and is being blocked for some reason. What I don't know is why, or how to fix it, so any help there would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set up you have should work (you might want to add an entry to the hosts file on either side to make life easier, but not necessary). I have the same set up and it works. Usually, it needs to completely shutdown the VM and boot it up again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried an host-only adapter. I had this problem with a custom server solution I was working on and it seemed to fix it. I don't know why but its worth a shot. Tell me if it work for you.

Comment: Won't this cause problems for accessing the repo from other machines?